# How can I map data onto a mesh grid in python?

Tags: python, visualization, mesh

I have a set of coordinate points I want to map onto a meshgrid. I have generated the meshgrid as such:

```
import numpy as np

a = -4
b = 4
z = 50
x = np.linspace(a, b, z)
y = np.linspace(a, b, z)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
```

I have an array of how the position of a particle changes with time, and I would like to map the positions onto the meshgrid for visualization of the change of particle position. How can I do that?

Comment: Hey there, could you provide the array that defines the position of the particle?

Comment: It is an array (2,2500), so essentially x and y coordinates for 2500 time steps. I want to plot the x and y coordinates on the meshgrid.

Comment: Check out the answer that I’ve posted and let me know if that works or not.

Comment: It worked, thank you! Is there a way I could do this with quiver?

Comment: Glad I could help, please remember to select my answer when you get a chance. For quiver you'd have to define two arrays that correspond to the particles direction. Check out the docs here. https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.quiver.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given what you provided, I gave your z direction a bit of texture so that I could plot the mesh w/ contours.

`>>> zz = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=1, size=(50,50))`

Also created a random path for your particle

```
>>> xp = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=6, size=50)
>>> yp = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=6, size=50)
```

and here is the final plot

```
>>> h = plt.contourf(x, y, zz)
>>> plt.axis('scaled')
>>> plt.colorbar()
>>> plt.plot(xp,yp,'o-',color='yellow')
```

[image]